# Image not showing in Crystal report for Visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have created a report then created a field in xsd with System.Byte as datatype.
Then passed values from C# to crystal report. But image is not shown in CR.
When I open rpt file the byte field showing as number(*when hover mouse over the byte field*).
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dataset XSD I changed the datatype from **System.Byte** to **System.Byte[]**
And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in crystal report we can not dynamically load the image through the diagrammatically.

If you use the MS-Sql server then store your image into Database with Image DataType and then Load the Table in XSD. I face same problem in past. As per my thinking this is only way to load image into CR. In CR use the Image object for loading value from the Database.